# jquery lazy load content in div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I want to load the content in div.I got many jquery scoll plugins but all are they for whole page load.I want to load content in existing div when scroll reaches at bottom of div.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this using JQuery and Ajax:

```
var loading = false;//to prevent duplicate

function loadNewContent(){       
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: url_to_new_content    
        success:function(data){
            if(data != ""){
                loading = false;
                $("#div-to-update").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}

//scroll DIV's Bottom 
$('#div-to-update').on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        if(!loading){
            loading = true;
            loadNewContent();//call function to load content when scroll reachs DIV bottom                
        }   
    }
})


//scroll to PAGE's bottom
var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
if  ((winTop / (docHeight - winHeight)) > 0.95) {       
    if(!loading){
        loading = true;
        loadNewContent();//call function to load content when scroll reachs PAGE bottom                
    }       
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TMk35/)

Comment: I dont want the scroll at bottom of page .I want the scroll in div and want to load the content in div not on whole page

Comment: `$("#div-to-update").html(data);` loads the content in `DIV`. I have update the code for the `DIV` scrolling.

Comment: Thanks a Lot that saved my lot of time .Thank you So much

Comment: please keep in touch.

Comment: I couldn't get the .on to fire. I'm trying to trigger it with waypoints.js instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using JQuery and this [lazyload plugin](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy).

Your div:

```
<div data-src="transparent.png" url="http://stackoverflow.com"></div>
```

Use `beforeLoad` callback:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("div[url]").lazy({
        beforeLoad: function (element) {
            element.load(element.attr("url"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but just to be complete: As said before, you could use [jQuery.Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy) for this. But I would not do it the here shown way. :) There is already a plugin for loading `<div>` content via AJAX too.

**Add the Plugin to your page:** (*you will need jQuery or Zepto as well*)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.1/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.1/plugins/jquery.lazy.ajax.min.js"></script>
```

**Prepare your div's:** (*note the `data-loader` and `data-src` attributes*)

```
<div data-loader="ajax" data-src="ajax.html"></div>
```

**And start using Lazy:**

```
$(function() {
    $("div[data-src]").Lazy();
});
```

That's it! The content given in `data-src` will be loaded whenever the user reaches the `<div>` by scrolling. More inormations [here](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins).

Comment: **Type: Offtop**. Excuse me, eisbehr, can you read when you will have a free time [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63753845/5951529) — how is it possible to do lazy loading for comments on the site via your jQuery.Lazy plugin? Thanks.